# Slides presentation with UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to do an app for iPad which will have something like a "slides presentation". Is it possible to do it with one single UIImageView that changes the image it shows ? And for the user change the slide, what can I use ? There's a particular button or arrow for this purpose ? (I'm looking for a simply solution because I'm really beginner).
Thanks!

Comment: you can use ICarousel custom library to do so it is easy check Code Here -- <https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel>

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your questions are Yes and kinda yes.

You can use an NSTimer or perform a selector with a delay to change the image in an imageView to act as a slide show, and you can also add a button that calls an action which changes the image.

Comment: Hmm.. but there's a more appropriate button for this ? Because I think that a regular round button would be a bit weird for changing slides..

Comment: Create a custom button and add it as an subview.